# Whats the difference in JMeter thread group between 50 threads 5 second ramp up and ...?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Whats the difference in JMeter between:

```
(a) 50 threads 5 second ramp up and 1 loop count

(b) 10 threads 1 second ramp up and 5 loop count
```

For me (a) and (b) seem to be the same thing, 10 threads will be instantiated every second for a total of 5 seconds.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ramp-up period **doesn't effect** total number of threads. see [user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen

So both scenarios will be executed 50 times, the difference is the order of the threads. In your case let's assume each thread takes ~5 minutes

Scenario a (without encountering any bottleneck) will take ~5 minutes (+5 seconds ramp up)

While Scenario b will take approximately 5 times more because each loop will start after threads ends. 5 minutes will take for each loop - ~25 minutes (+1 second ramp up)

Also you can have limitation on your server that doesn't allow 50 threads executing in 5 seconds same operation so Scenario a will be impossible to execute.